# Rails server error "bad Request-Line" with HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I am getting this error when I am starting my server

```
    [2016-01-06 18:57:00] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03B0�c�ezc�*�[S'.
    [2016-01-06 18:57:00] ERROR bad URI `�\x00�7���\x04^\b��\x02W'���U��1lH|�A�t\x00\x00\x1E�+�/\x00��\x14�\x13�'.
    [2016-01-06 18:57:00] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x02�\x05\x01\x1D��~�-\x01Lω\x01���L"��\f� ����[�\x0F�\x00\x00\x14�'.
    [2016-01-06 18:57:00] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x01

\x0E�|�s��(�9��4V:��*\f'\fh^衜&���-�\x00\x00\x14�'.
```

I disabled `config.force_ssl = false` and I also uninstalled thin... But every time when I open `localhost:3000`, it is automatically opening the HTTPS version `https://localhost:3000/`.

Comment: Try to clear your browsers cache, reload, another browsers etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. The https may be in the browser cache. Clear the browser cache, close the browser and retry.
2. As I [explained in this article](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/review/using-https-with-ruby-on-rails/article.md), the `force_ssl` configuration also sets the HSTS header. This header tells the browser that any subsequent request must for that domain be sent to HTTPS instead of HTTP (until the previously set expiration which by default is 1 year). You will have to also remove that domain from the browser HTTP list. How you delete the domain depends on the specific browser. [Here's an example with Chrome and Firefox](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers).